Who are these mutants in "X-Men '97" season 1, episode 5?
In X-Men '97 season 1, episode 5, who are these four mutants present on the island of Genosha?


I don't think the girl next to Glob is Loa. She doesn't bear much resemblance to her, certainly not as much as the character I identified as Loa in this prior question. She also transforms into a bird in the episode, which isn't one of Loa's powers. I don't know of any Marvel mutant from the comics that fits the profile; Carmen Cruz is the closest candidate, but not quite there. Perhaps she'll be named in the next episode, since she was shown again near the end of this one.

"Unnamed Parrot Mutant" - https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_%2797_Season_1_5

The Marvel wiki has now named her as Carmen Cruz (AKA Gimmick) but I can't see any specific justification for doing so.

Three are easy to identify.
Leech (with his iconic hat)

Herman Glob (with his characteristic translucent skin)

Pixie (with her trademark ears and pink hair)

The fourth I'm not so sure about.

NerdRiot, who have inside contacts at the studio, claim (at 14.14 in this 'easter egg video' that she's an entirely original character for the TV show.

I thought the character was Lin Li but no, I've mistaken her with another character.

@Clockwork - I've ruled out Nature Girl, Lin Li and Morph. It could be Carmen Cruz since she's a metamorph.

inb4 it's a new character whose name is just going to be Parrot

@Clockwork - My money is on Bird-Girl

Morphing between human and parrot forms (if that's all she can do) is a pretty crappy power for an X-Man. Makes Gambit look extremely powerful and useful by comparison.

@LogicDictates - Turning into a bird seems moderately useful for surveillance, etc. but yes, there are lots of mutants with powers that are far less stupid

If that is her only power and she isn't a previously-named character, they should probably give her the codename 'Pretty Polly.'
